# What does this hard drive authentication after login in LXDE mean?

Tags: 16.04, login, authentication, policykit, udisks

I am using LXDE on Ubuntu 16.04. When I wake it up from suspension, I login in, and then another authentication window appears. What does that mean? Is it necessary? If not, how can I get rid of the second authentication?
Thanks.

[image]

---

Update:

I found a solution at  https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2274234&page=2&p=13522130#post13522130

> I had to add the following file to authorize myself to udisks2's
>   "org.freedesktop.udisks2.ata-smart-update" action.
>
> ```
> /etc/polkit-1/rules.d/00_user_blah.rules
>
> polkit.addRule(function (action, subject) {
> var YES = polkit.Result.YES;
> var permission = {
> "org.freedesktop.udisks2.ata-smart-update": YES
> };
>
>
> if (subject.user == "blah") {
> return permission[action.id];
> }
>
> return polkit.Result.NOT_HANDLED;
> });
> ```

Can someone explain how `udisks2`, `/etc/polkit-1/rules.d/00_user_blah.rules`, and "org.freedesktop.udisks2.ata-smart-update" action work together?

Is `/etc/polkit-1/rules.d/00_user_blah.rules` written in some programming language?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Polkit is an authorization framework, while your system is up  an authentication agent is running on the background, `udisks` asks to do a pervilaged action equal to "org.freedesktop.udisks2.ata-smart-update" finaly polkit based on the ruels decide whatever it should allow, ask for password or deny this request.

polkit rules are written in JavaScript.