# How are hddtemp, udisks2 and libatasmart compared to each other?

Tags: hard-drive, temperature, lm-sensors

I posted a problem of authentication for my hard drive at [What does this authentication after login in LXDE mean?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/924421/what-does-this-authentication-after-login-in-lxde-mean)

I found someone said [the problem was caused by lm-sensors which uses udisks2](https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2274234&s=e1fa596621642859754a060baabea0e4&p=13306318#post13306318)

> It's caused by lm-sensors. Click on the thermometer indicator (which is lm-sensors) -> Preferences -> Providers -> Then untick 'Enable support of udisks2'. That seems to make it go away. It probably is still a configuration type bug, but I'm not sure if I really need the udisks2 reading for what I use lm-sensors for. Hope this helps!

I followed the advice, and opened the thermometer indicator (which is lm-sensors) -> Preferences -> Providers. I unticked `Enable support of udisks2`, and because I would like to check my hard drive temperature, I ticked `Enable support for hddtemp daemon`.

[image]

To understand what I was doing, I found  https://wpitchoune.net/psensor/faq.html

> For hard disk drives, psensor can use:
>
> udisks2: added since 1.1.2 release. It is the default and recommended
>   provider.
>
> hddtemp: verify that it is correctly reporting temperature by using
>   the command: sudo hddtemp /dev/sda. It is the default provider until
>   1.1.2 release.
>
> atasmart library: before the 1.1.2 release it can be enabled by using
>   the command line option --use-libatasmart.

How are hddtemp, udisks2 and libatasmart compared to each other? Do I miss something if I tick hddtemp and untick udisks2?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

As you know they have nothing to do with each other, "psensor" is just a temperature monitoring application which uses other tools to gather its data.

For me because of permissions only `udisks2` is working. anyway, you should test the output of these commands, if you get the same result (which you should) then there is no difference.

so they're just different sources.

---

As far as I know all of them gather their data using hard disk smart.

For "udisks2" use:

```
udisksctl dump /dev/sdX | grep -i temp
```

For "libsmart" you can look for smart data yourself, use:

```
sudo smartctl -a /dev/sdX | grep -i temp
```

And finally:

```
hddtemp /dev/sdX
```

Comment: Thanks. I found that changing from udisks2 to hddtemp doesn't make the hard drive authentication go away. So i tried another solution which works https://askubuntu.com/questions/924421/what-does-this-authentication-after-login-in-lxde-mean